# How should I do that logging in sbt project?

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, securesocial

```
[error] s.c.p.TwitterProvider - [securesocial] error retrieving request token
oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException: Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match.
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:243) ~[signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar:na]
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:193) ~[signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar:na]
    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:74) ~[signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.oauth.OAuth.retrieveRequestToken(OAuth.scala:38) ~[play-ws_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at securesocial.core.OAuth1Client$Default$$anonfun$retrieveRequestToken$1.apply(OAuth1Provider.scala:69) ~[securesocial_2.11-3.0-M3.jar:3.0-M3]
[error] s.c.ProviderController - Unable to log user in. An exception was thrown
securesocial.core.AuthenticationException: null
    at securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider$$anonfun$authenticate$1.applyOrElse(OAuth1Provider.scala:141) ~[securesocial_2.11-3.0-M3.jar:3.0-M3]
    at securesocial.core.OAuth1Provider$$anonfun$authenticate$1.applyOrElse(OAuth1Provider.scala:138) ~[securesocial_2.11-3.0-M3.jar:3.0-M3]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:215) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191) [scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
```

I want to check a requests. How I do setting the logger into sbt subproject(jar files)?

Comment: have you read this: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Howto/logging.html

Comment: So you want to log the output of running SBT?

Comment: No, I want to set logger(e.g. play.api.Logger) before OAuth1Provider.scala:69. But it is already build to the jar file.  How set logger into OAuth1Provider.scala?

Comment: Does the jar use log4j?

Comment: Use the securesocial.